# Can $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{x + \sqrt{1-x^2}} \,dx$ be evaluated without trig substitutions?

Tags: integration

This question is from Trinity College Cambridge's interview:
$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{x + \sqrt{1-x^2}} \,dx$$
Is there any way to solve this question without using trigonometric substiutions?

Comment: @player3236.. Yeah just saw 

Comment: Why are you disinterested in a trig substitution?

Comment: @Allawonder Because it's the question from Trinity.

Comment: Is trig. substitution banned at Trinity college? @oldboy

Comment: @ArcticChar Cmon, man... It's not banned. IT'S BANNED IN THIS QUESTION! And the question is: "Can you solve this without XYZ"? Which part you don't understand?

Comment: The only thing i do not understand is your reply to Allawonder, @oldboy

Comment: @Oldboy Or OP could be asking if this could be solved without trig substitutions out of curiosity.

Answer (score 3):

Trig substitution may be banned, but it gives us some key insights.

If you perform the trig substitution $x = \sin(\theta)$, where $0 \le \theta \le \pi/2$, then we get
$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x + \sqrt{1 - x^2}} \, \mathrm{d}x = \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\cos(\theta)}{\sin(\theta) + \cos(\theta)} \, \mathrm{d}\theta.$$

On the other hand, if we perform a slightly different trig substitution of $x = \cos(\alpha)$, with $0 \le \alpha \le \pi/2$, then
$$\begin{align} \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x + \sqrt{1 - x^2}} \, \mathrm{d}x &= \int_{\pi/2}^0\frac{-\sin(\alpha)}{\cos(\alpha) + \sin(\alpha)} \, \mathrm{d}\alpha \\ \\ &= \int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin(\alpha)}{\cos(\alpha) + \sin(\alpha)} \, \mathrm{d}\alpha.\end{align}$$
Summing these two integrals, we get
\begin{align*}
2\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x + \sqrt{1 - x^2}} \, \mathrm{d}x &= \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\cos(\theta)}{\sin(\theta) + \cos(\theta)} \, \mathrm{d}\theta + \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\sin(\theta)}{\sin(\theta) + \cos(\theta)} \, \mathrm{d}\theta \\
&= \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\sin(\theta) + \cos(\theta)}{\sin(\theta) + \cos(\theta)} \, \mathrm{d}\theta = \frac{\pi}{2},
\end{align*}
hence the integral should be $\pi/4$.

---

How do we shortcut the trig substitution here? The key insight seems to be that the trigonometric integral produces something interesting when $\sin$ and $\cos$ are interchanged, so the original integral should, hopefully, yield something interesting under a substitution of $u = \sqrt{1 - x^2}$. We have,
$$\mathrm{du} = \frac{-x}{\sqrt{1 - x^2}} \, \mathrm{d}x = -\frac{x}{u} \, \mathrm{d}x,$$
and so
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x + \sqrt{1 - x^2}} \, \mathrm{d}x &= \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x(x + \sqrt{1 - x^2})} \cdot x \, \mathrm{d}x\\
&= \int_1^0 \frac{1}{1 - u^2 + u\sqrt{1 - u^2}} \cdot (-u) \, \mathrm{d}u \\
&= \int_0^1 \frac{u}{1 - u^2 + u\sqrt{1 - u^2}} \, \mathrm{d}u \\
&= \int_0^1 \frac{\frac{u}{\sqrt{1 - u^2}}}{\sqrt{1 - u^2} + u} \, \mathrm{d}u.
\end{align*}
When we add these two integrals together,
\begin{align*}2\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x + \sqrt{1 - x^2}} \, \mathrm{d}x &= \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x + \sqrt{1 - x^2}} \, \mathrm{d}x + \int_0^1 \frac{\frac{x}{\sqrt{1 - x^2}}}{x + \sqrt{1 - x^2}} \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \int_0^1 \frac{1 + \frac{x}{\sqrt{1 - x^2}}}{x + \sqrt{1 - x^2}} \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - x^2}} \, \mathrm{d}x.
\end{align*}
I feel a little dirty about the next step, but from here I reference the standard table of integrals and the fundamental theorem of calculus to conclude that
$$2\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x + \sqrt{1 - x^2}} \, \mathrm{d}x = [\sin^{-1}(x)]_0^1 = \frac{\pi}{2} - 0 = \frac{\pi}{2},$$
hence the integral is $\pi/4$ as predicted.

Comment: ...and you feel dirty for a reason.

Comment: @Oldboy What are you implying?

Comment: @Oldboy Yeah. What I wanted to do was exactly what Archille Hui and compare it with a standard area, but I tried applying integration by parts on the expression itself, and it went nowhere. Did it feel less dirty using arctan? ;-)

Comment: @user837206 Ok, it did not :) +1 for your answer.

Comment: This is how I would have done it. Port the trick that resolves it after a trig substitution to the "non-trigonometic" side :-)

Answer (score 1):

Change variable to $y = \sqrt{1-x^2} \iff x = \sqrt{1-y^2}$, we have

$$\begin{align}\mathcal{I}& \stackrel{def}{=}
\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{x+\sqrt{1-x^2}}
= \int_1^0 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-y^2}+y}\left(\sqrt{1-y^2}\right)'dy\\
&= \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-y^2}+y}\frac{y}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}dy\end{align}$$
Renaming variable $y$ back to $x$ and take average of the two expression of $\mathcal{I}$, we obtain
$$\mathcal{I} = \frac12 \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x+\sqrt{1-x^2}}\left(1 + \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right) dx = \frac12\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

Notice $$\left(x \sqrt{1-x^2}\right)' = \sqrt{1-x^2} - \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} = 2\sqrt{1-x^2} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$
Integrate both sides over $[0,1]$, we get

$$2\int_0^1\sqrt{1-x^2} dx - \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} = \left[x\sqrt{1-x^2}\right]_0^1 = 0$$
As a result, $$\mathcal{I} = \int_0^1 \sqrt{1-x^2}dx$$
Geometrically, LHS is the area of a quarter unit circle. By some variant of definition of $\pi$, the area of a unit circle is $\pi$. From this, we can deduce
$$\mathcal{I} = \frac{\pi}{4}$$

Answer (score 0):

Another way to compute the same thing: introduct substitution $x=
\frac1u$. the integral becomes:

$$I=\int_0^1\frac{dx}{x+\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\int_1^\infty\frac{udu}{u^2(1+\sqrt{u^2-1})}$$

Another substitution:

$$u^2-1=z^2$$

The integral becomes:

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{zdz}{(1+z^2)(1+z)}$$

You can easily show that:

$$\frac{z}{(1+z^2)(1+z)}=\frac12\frac{1+z}{1+z^2}-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1+z}$$

So the integral becomes:

$$\frac12\int_0^\infty\frac{dz}{1+z^2}+\frac12\int_0^\infty\frac{zdz}{1+z^2}-\frac12\int_0^\infty\frac{dz}{1+z}=$$

$$\frac12\arctan z|_0^\infty+\frac 14\ln(1+z^2)|_0^\infty-\frac12\ln(1+z)|_0^\infty=$$

$$\frac\pi4-\frac14\ln\frac{1+z^2}{(1+z)^2}|_0^\infty=\frac\pi4$$

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=\frac 1{x+\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\frac{x-\sqrt{1-x^2}}{(x+\sqrt{1-x^2})(x-\sqrt{1-x^2})}=\frac{x-\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x^2-(1-x^2)}=\frac{x-\sqrt{1-x^2}}{2x^2-1}$$
$$=\frac{x}{2x^2-1}+\frac{\sqrt{(1-x)(1+x)}}{(1-\sqrt{2}x)(1+\sqrt{2}x)}$$
you could try and do PFD on this but honestly it doesnt look like that nice of an expression :/

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{{\large\bf Hint}:}$

Set $\ds{x = \pars{{1 \over t} - t}
{\ic \over 2} \iff t = \ic x - \root{1 - x^{2}}}$. You get
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{1}{\dd x \over x + \root{1 - x^{2}}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{-1}^{\ic}\bracks{-{\pars{1 - \ic}/2 \over t}
+ {t \over t^{2} - \ic}}\dd t
\end{align}